# Postgres PgAdmin 3: Server doesn't listen - Tried everything

Tags: postgresql, psql

I tried opening ports in IPTables,
Set Listen address to *
Added
**host all all 23.81.27.0/24 trust**
and even
**host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust**

YouGetSignal shows the port is closed, and i can't connect to my DB via PgAdmin.

I get

> could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
>   Is the server running on host "23.81.27.206" and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections on port 5432?

Any ideas?

I already tried to reboot Postgresql, IPtables, and the server.

Comment: Probably blocked by a firewall. Can you log into the server and connect via `psql -h 127.0.0.1`?

Comment: @NickBarnes yes, i can.

Comment: Then Postgres is listening, and the problem is somewhere else. Are you behind a firewall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was IPTables after all. I did "Service iptables stop" And i can connect. I can't manage to allow my ip/open that port. But i guess this is how i have to do it. i just enable it whenever im done.

Answer (score 0):

With this error

> could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
>   Is the server running on host "23.81.27.206" and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections on port 5432?

no need to modify `hba_file`. Either `listen_address` in postgres.conf not set to listen on external iface, or firewall blocks it/ not translating/ othernetwork issues. First case often people modify listen_address in wrong `postgres.conf` or do not restart server. To make sure it did not happen to you, ssh to server, `psql` to it and check

```
show config_file;
show listen_addresses;
```

If those ok, then still on remotes shell :

```
psql -h 23.81.27.206
```

If you get connected, stop looking into postgres config - check network (firewall, PAT,NAT,routes, your client connection ((maybe you not connected to the Internet?..)))

Comment: # listen_addresses = '*'  # what IP address(es) to listen on;

it's set to '*'

Comment: it found postgresql.conf and listen_address is set to localhost.

Comment: okay just setup correctly and now shows */star/ when i do show listen_addresses; but still has same error. I added my ip in hba conf; this is wha tit looks like

Comment: host    all         all         23.81.27.0/24    trust

Comment: I thought 23.81.27.206 was your server IP. hba_file has rules for client IPs. what do you see when you run `psql -h 23.81.27.206` on remote host (after you ssh to it).

Comment: [root@jdc-user ~]# psql -h 23.81.27.206
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "23.81.27.206" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?